# How to round up to the 16th decimal place in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to know how to extend to the 16th decimal place in SQLite e.g

```
SELECT 799.9/150.0 --Answer rounded up to the 16th decimal place.
```

Comment: I'd suggest reading https://www.sqlite.org/floatingpoint.html#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite has a function called [`round`](https://www.w3resource.com/sqlite/core-functions-round.php#:%7E:text=SQLite%20round()%20function%20rounds,is%20assumed%20to%20be%200.&text=A%20number%20which%20will%20be%20rounded%20upto%20D%20decimal%20places.&text=A%20number%20indicating%20up%20to,places%20N%20will%20be%20rounded.) which can be used to round floating point numbers to a specified precision:

> SQLite round() function rounds a floating-point value t up to a number of digits to the right of the decimal point. If the 2nd argument (rounded digits) is omitted, it is assumed to be 0.

To round a number up to the 16th decimal place, you'd have to modify your query to look like this:

```
SELECT round(799.9/150.0, 16)
```

This outputs the number `5.332666666666667`.

If you want no decimals at all, you can omit the second parameter:

```
SELECT round(799.9/150.0)
```

This will return `5.0`

Comment: thanks for your answer but it is not up to the 16th decimal, it ends at the 15th. I have tried this already, but I get to the 15the decimal.

Comment: An issue is that ***because only about the first 15 significant digits of each number are stored accurately*** an extract from https://www.sqlite.org/floatingpoint.html#floating_point_accuracy. i.e. 799.9/150.0 results in the same value.

Comment: Indeed, totally forgot the practical side of this problem. SQLite simply does not store more than 15 digits after the decimal point, that means my answer won't help because it's not possible to get a better floating-point precision in SQLite.

Comment: @chinanu SQLite uses 8 byte IEEE floats, so the maximum precision is technically limited, and 15 digits is about the best you can get with this data type. There is an extension to do arbitrary precision calculations (https://www.sqlite.org/floatingpoint.html#the_decimal_c_extension), or you can register your own application-defind functions for that purpose (https://www.sqlite.org/appfunc.html).

Comment: To be pedantic, the maximum precision of IEEE 754 64-bit (aka `double`) floating-point format is 53 *binary* digits, which works out to approximately 15.95 decimal digits.  This includes both sides of the `.`, so if you have one digit (the "5") on the left side, you can only expect 14 accurate digits on the right side.